# Angular & Bootstrap Modal inside nested loop

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Hello i wanted to use Modal in angular to show the details of a row in a table where the have the same id
But for some reason when I open the Modal, it always shows me the data of the first row of the table only
The rest of the rows dont work

```
<div  *ngFor="let suite of tb_suites ">
                  <div class="row border-bottom" >
                    <button class="col-2 btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" attr.data-target="#Modal{{suite.Execution_Id}}" aria-expanded="false" >
                      <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      <i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="col-5">{{suite.Suite_Name}}</div>
                    <div class="col-1 pass" *ngIf="suite.Suite_Status === 'PASS'">{{(suite.Suite_Status)}}</div>
                    <div class="col-1 fail" *ngIf="suite.Suite_Status === 'FAIL'">{{(suite.Suite_Status)}}</div>
                    <div class=" col-1 pass">{{suite.Suite_Pass}}</div>
                  <div class="col-1 fail">{{suite.Suite_Fail}}</div>
                  <div class="col-1 skip">{{suite.Suite_Skip}}</div>
                  </div>
                  
                  <!--Detalis2-->
                  <div attr.id="Modal{{suite.Execution_Id}}" class="modal fade " tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="headingOne" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class=" modal-dialog" role="document">
                      
                      <div  class="container-fluid row secondrow bg-dark ">
                        
                          <div class="col-md-5 mt-2">Test Name</div>
                          <div class="col-md-2 mt-2">Test Status</div>
                          <div class="col-md-5 mt-2">Test Error</div>
                        
                      </div>
                      
                      <div  *ngFor="let test of tb_tests">
                        <div class="row border-bottom" *ngIf="test.Execution_Id===suite.Execution_Id">
                          <div class="col-md-5">{{test.Test_Name}}</div>
                          <div class="col-md-1 pass" *ngIf="test.Test_Status === 'PASS'">{{(test.Test_Status)}}</div>
                          <div class="col-md-1 fail" *ngIf="test.Test_Status === 'FAIL'">{{(test.Test_Status)}}</div>
                          <div class="col-md-5" >{{test.Test_Error}}</div>
                        </div>
                        
                      </div>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                      
                      
                      
                      
                      
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!--Details2-->

                </div>
```

Any help for how to make it show me the details of each row normally where the IDs are equal
The table of tb_tests has a foreign key Execution_Id from tb_suites

Answer (score 0):

i guess by default when calling the "#Modal{{suite.Execution_Id}}" its going with a 0. thats why youre only see #1 record. try to send the index as "#Modal{{suite.index}}"

Comment: I added  let i = index with my *ngfor and changed the modal id into "#Modal{{i+1}}, the details now are shown in all the the rows but same problem it only shows me the details of the forst row for each row